# get track element src from external url

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

i have an openload video url. video contains 2 subs (vtt).

```
<track kind="captions" src="https://thumb.oloadcdn.net/subtitle/aaaaaaaaaaa/J8i5nTIAM3w.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default />
<track kind="captions" src="https://thumb.oloadcdn.net/subtitle/aaaaaaaaaaa/zwLybxvUj_s.vtt" srclang="tr" label="Turkish" default />
<track kind="captions" srclang="en" label="▤ Load SRT/VTT from PC~PC~" class="olsrt"/>
<track kind="captions" srclang="en" label="▤ Load SRT/VTT from URL~URL~"/>
<track kind="captions" srclang="en" label="❞ Size +~SzP~" class="olsrt"/>
<track kind="captions" srclang="en" label="❞ Size -~SzM~"/>
```

video embed is on my page.its external url so
how can i display second vtt link on my page. (srclang="tr" label="Turkish") on my page using html or javascript

Answer (score 0):

using `jquery` you can do this:

`var url = $('track[srclang="tr"]').attr('src');`

https://jsfiddle.net/yuqutgzf/